# updating a range within a for each loop in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a search sub that looks through the cells in one range and then given some parameter finds a match in a second range, there are multiple values that are the same so in this case I want to return the next value in the second range. I was thinking that I could have a for each loop that whenever there was a value that was the same in the first range the next time it looped through the second range was adjusted to exclude the first value that i returned from it, but if it is a new value from the first range then it would search through all of the second range again but I cant seem to get it to work (it is giving me an error of a type mismatch for the first if statement)

```
    Sub mySearch()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

Set rng1 = Sheets("Deduped NS Data").Range("E2:E142")
Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(2, 1)

    For Each i In rng1
        If i = i.Offset(1) And i = rng2 And i.Offset(, 3) = rng2.Offset(, 8) Then
            i.Offset(, 2) = rng2.Offset(, 7)
            rng2 = rng2.Offset(1)

        ElseIf i = rng2 And i.Offset(, 3) = rng2.Offset(, 8) Then
            i.Offset(, 2) = rng2.Offset(, 7)
            rng2 = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(2, 1)

        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: How is it not working? Are values not being displayed?

Comment: it says there is a type mismatch in the first if statement

Comment: Check for an error (e.g. `#N/A`) in the cell that are being referenced there.

Comment: so it is actually filling in the for the first cell but then the second cell doesnt match the conditions so I think it never moves on. I originally was using a double for each loop to go through the second range as well but then it was just returning the final value that matched for every single one. im not sure what I could use to iterate through the second range without just returning the last value every time again